# Diferença entre estas duas declarações de funções imediatas

Tags: javascript

**Qual é a diferença entre:**

```
(function() {
    console.log('Hello :)');
})();
```

**e:**

```
(function() {
    console.log('Hello :)');
}());
```

**?** Os dois trechos de código fazem a mesma coisa, então eu fiquei na dúvida se há alguma diferença além da escrita ou se são apenas formas diferentes de fazer a mesma coisa, sem implicações de performance e etc...

Comment: (Em síntaxe elas são diferentes coisas.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

São apenas duas formas diferentes para realizar a execução imediata de uma função javascript sem diferença de performance entre elas.

Essa questão sobre qual das formas seria a melhor para se utilizar se encontra respondida na comunidade. Segue o link: [Immediate function invocation syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939386/immediate-function-invocation-syntax)